# Model Predicts Badly on Real-World Data

Tags: deep-learning, keras, nlp

I know this is probably a really easy fix, but I've been stuck on this for a while. I'm a noobie to both machine learning and programming in general.  My data is from this dataset. https://www.kaggle.com/ozlerhakan/spam-or-not-spam-dataset

I made a model that can predict whether or not an email is spam email, and it does so reasonably well, getting an 84% accuracy with the validation data. But when I try to make it predict on a new string, it seems to be predicting on a character-by-character basis. Below is the code that I used to preprocess the training(and testing) data. I would've copy-pasted the required code, but when I look at the draft, it looks terrible. So here's the link to my notebook. https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1EnoNFR5CFi85hOrW8ihx66QWb6sToKAL?usp=sharing
I tried to debug the function by putting various print statements all over. I've come to the conclusion that the problem spot is when I try to one-hot encode the words. I need those words to be one-hot encoded because that is how I trained the model.  But I don't know how to fix that. I would really appreciate some help with this. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Welcome to DataScienceSE. I'm not at all familiar with keras but I think you're right: from a quick look at your code I saw that you redo a one-hot encoding when you test.  The general principle with one-hot encoding is that the encoding is determined during training and then the same encoding must be applied when applying the model, otherwise the indexes are all messed up. I can't tell you how to do it with keras, maybe [this explanation](https://towardsdatascience.com/building-a-one-hot-encoding-layer-with-tensorflow-f907d686bf39) can help.

Comment: First of all, thanks for taking the time to respond! I forgot that since one-hot can't be instantiated,  it wouldn't have a dictionary of any sort. But I still don't understand why it's getting encoded on a character-by-character basis. From what I can tell, the only difference between a training string and that sample string was that the sample string had 3 quotes. I'm not too familiar with raw TensorFlow code so I couldn't really understand the article. I might just decide to use the Tokenizer instead.

Answer (score 0):

You are using multiple frameworks (pandas, keras / tensorflow, nltk, reg, scikit-learn) and doing a lot of manually processing. It would be better if you used a single framework. A single framework would automatic many of the steps and appropriately handle training and prediction. The result would be creating the same one-hot encoding scheme at the token level.